# How to share some value using a global variable from Angular2 component to a Javascript method

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to access a global javascript variable inside angular2 component and vice-versa. I assign the default value inside index.html within the script tag, I am able read this value inside the angular2 component. but when I edit/reassign some other value to that variable inside the angular2 component, I couldn't access/get the edited value in javascript.

I am boostraping in main.ts

```
export function main(dateColumnName: any)
{
    platformBrowserDynamic([{ provide: 'dateColumnName', useValue: dateColumnName }]).bootstrapModule(AppModule)
}
```

In Index.html I am importing like below

```
 <script>
        var dateColumnName = "WEEK_END_DT";//assigned with default value
        System.import('app/main').then((module) => {
            module.main(dateColumnName);
        });

       function myFunc()
       {
           alert(dateColumnName);//I need to access the edited value from here...
       }
</script>
```

In my AppComponent, I inject the variable in the constructor as

```
export class AppComponent{

dateColumnName : any; //Local variable

constructor(  @Inject('dateColumnName') _dateColumnName: string)
{
_dateColumnName --> this input parameter contains the value specified in the index.html
}

method1()
{
    this.dateColumnName = "NewValue"//This newly assigned value to be accessed in index.html
}
```

I need to reassign some value inside my angular2 component, and use that value from a javascript method... basically I want to share some value from angular2 to javascript...

what is it I am missing here? how to reassign the variable?

Comment: you should be using shared service or store to achieve this. no other option.

Comment: @Aravind, can you share some example?

Comment: Providers don't work two ways.  If you want a global variable, just use a global variable

Comment: @Krishnan see this [**link**](http://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use window Object.
in your index.html you have a global variable:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
var testGlobalVar = 'initial value';
</script>
```

in the component's class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare var window: any; //DON'T FORGET ABOUT THIS ONE!!!

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
  }

  getGlobalVarValue() {
    console.log('testGlobalVar: ', window.testGlobalVar);

    return window.testGlobalVar;
  }

  setGlobalVarValue(value: string) {
    window.testGlobalVar = value;
    return window.testGlobalVar;
  }
}
```

and component's template/html:

```
<a (click)="getGlobalVarValue()">get global var value</a>
<br />
<a (click)="setGlobalVarValue('new value from angular2')">set global var value</a>
```

or you can access directly the global var without going via window Object:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare var testGlobalVar: any; // WITHOUT WINDOW OBJECT

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
  }

  getGlobalVarValue() {
    console.log('testGlobalVar: ', testGlobalVar);

    return testGlobalVar;
  }

  setGlobalVarValue(value: string) {
    testGlobalVar = value;
    return testGlobalVar;
  }
}
```

To have a better structure which will work with global properties/variables/methods, I'd create a separate service and inject it (dependency injection)!

Comment: Is it possible to use dependency injection to inject a global variable directly into the app?

Answer (score 1):

You can communicate between the components with the child-parent relationship or through the service.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

But there is a way through ngrx/store. This concept is similar to Redux. you can try it.